# How to update HTML elements in Svelte and Sveltekit via onMount

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, game-development, sveltekit

I am down with Covid and wanted to write a fun little game.  I am writing a Hangman Game in Svelte and Sveltekit.

I have most of the game written, but I a stuck revealing the divs of the hangman.

Here is the code:
https://timscodebase-didactic-palm-tree-7wx4w55459xfpxq5.github.dev/

In `src/lib/HangGrid.svelte`, am subscribing to `numberWrong` and am trying to react to when it changes.  it is working but I am getting errors trying to add a class to an element in a nodelist.

Here is the code:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { numberWrong } from '$lib/stores'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    $: console.log('numberWrong from grid', $numberWrong)
    $: wrong = $numberWrong - 1

    let pieces_of_man: NodeListOf<Element>
    const setPiecesOfMan = (pieces: NodeListOf<Element>) => {
        pieces_of_man = pieces
        console.log(pieces_of_man)
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        setPiecesOfMan(document.querySelectorAll('.piece_of_man'))
    })

    $: current_piece = pieces_of_man[wrong]

    // This gives the error
    $: current_piece.classList.remove('white')

    // This gives "
    $: console.log('current_piece', current_piece)
</script>
```

Here is the error:

```
[HMR][Svelte] Unrecoverable HMR error in <HangGrid>: next update will trigger a full reload
logError @ proxy.js?v=02947d2a:15
Proxy<HangGrid> @ proxy.js?v=02947d2a:380
create_if_block_2 @ +page.svelte:61
create_if_block_1 @ +page.svelte:57
create_if_block @ +page.svelte:56
update @ +page.svelte:55
update @ index.mjs:1273
flush @ index.mjs:1233
Promise.then (async)
schedule_update @ index.mjs:1184
make_dirty @ index.mjs:2066
(anonymous) @ index.mjs:2104
handleSubmit @ +page.svelte:40
(anonymous) @ index.mjs:428
HangGrid.svelte:18 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '-1')
    at $$self.$$.update (HangGrid.svelte:18:21)
    at init (index.mjs:2109:8)
    at new HangGrid (HangGrid.svelte:23:47)
    at createProxiedComponent (svelte-hooks.js?v=02947d2a:341:9)
    at new ProxyComponent (proxy.js?v=02947d2a:242:7)
    at new Proxy<HangGrid> (proxy.js?v=02947d2a:349:11)
    at Array.create_if_block_2 (+page.svelte:61:11)
    at Array.create_if_block_1 (+page.svelte:57:16)
    at Array.create_if_block (+page.svelte:56:16)
    at Object.update [as p] (+page.svelte:55:19)
```

Comment: The link to the code gives a 404. The error might go away with `$: current_piece?.classList.remove('white')` Did you go through the tutorial? https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics There is usually no reason to query the DOM or modify classList

Answer (score 0):

```
$: current_piece = pieces_of_man[wrong]

// This gives the error
$: current_piece.classList.remove('white')
```

As you're using SvelteKit, the above code runs on the server first before the DOM is mounted. Hence, the value of `pieces_of_man` is undefined, that results `current_piece` value to be -1 and that's why you receive an error when you're trying to set classList.

To make sure you only run it once the DOM is mounted try updating your code to this:

```js
<script lang="ts">
    import { numberWrong } from '$lib/stores'
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    $: console.log('numberWrong from grid', $numberWrong)
    $: wrong = $numberWrong - 1

    let pieces_of_man: NodeListOf<Element>
    let mounted = false // Tracks whether the DOM is mounted
    
    const setPiecesOfMan = (pieces: NodeListOf<Element>) => {
        pieces_of_man = pieces
        console.log(pieces_of_man)
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        setPiecesOfMan(document.querySelectorAll('.piece_of_man'))
        mounted = true // DOM is mounted
    })

    $: mounted && current_piece = pieces_of_man[wrong] // Runs only when DOM is mounted

    $: mounted && current_piece.classList.remove('white') // Runs only when DOM is mounted
 
    $: console.log('current_piece', current_piece)
</script>
```

Also updating DOM imperatively is not recommended in Svelte. I would suggest you to go over the [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/classes) in Svelte to get some idea on how to manipulate classes.

Thanks! Please take care and get well soon.

Comment: Why not set `mounted` in `onMount` after `setPiecesOfMan`? In SvelteKit there's alternatively `browser` https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser

Comment: @Corrl Oh yes, that was a mistake. I never realized I put the `mounted = true` inside the `setPieciesOfMan` function. And yeah, using browser is also an option. Thanks man!

Comment: I am getting errors

Comment: I am getting this error with your code:

Comment: Invalid assignment target
   19 |      })
   20 |  
   21 |      $ |  mounted && current_piece = pieces_of_man[wrong] // Runs only when DOM is mounted
      |         ^
   22 |  
   23 |      $ |  mounted && current_piece.classList.remove('white') // Runs only when DOM is mounte